# CRM 2011: Fields updated during PostRetrieve not saving when Form is saved

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have some code in a PostAccountRetrieve (i've removed lines):

```
Entity entity = (Entity)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"];
Account account = entity.ToEntity();
...
account.test_TerminationDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)subscriber.TerminationDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
account.test_MaxPositions = subscriber.MaxLivePos;
account.test_Locked = subscriber.Locked;

entity.EntityState = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityState.Changed;
...
```

The fields on the form are filled in by the code, however, when the user presses "Save", it does not save these values with the account. I thought setting the EntityState would take care of this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think EntityState will help you in a Post Retrieve plugin.  I'm pretty sure your problem is that the CRM form is smart enough to only submit values that were actually changed.  You are "changing" these values in Post Retrieve, which happens as the form loads, so the form doesn't think these values have changed and doesn't submit them when you click Save.

The solution is to use this javascript in the form load:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“test_TerminationDate”).setSubmitMode(“always”);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“test_MaxPositions”).setSubmitMode(“always”);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“test_Locked”).setSubmitMode(“always”);
```

This should bypass CRM's "smarts" so those fields always get submitted on Save.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you think there is a way to get to these form attributes from within the plugin? Trying to keep all the code in one place.

Comment: Nope - you are dealing with two different "tiers."  Your Retrieve plugin is running on the server before the client form is even rendered, so your plugin will have no concept of the form yet.

An interesting possibility would be to add a fourth field called "FieldsToForceSubmit" or something like that.  In your Retrieve plugin, set it to a comma-delimited list of the other 3 fields.  Then on the client side, write some generic Javascript that would loop through those fields and setSubmitMode on them.  This way you don't have to maintain the client side code at least.

Comment: Finally found time to try out your solution. Setting the submit mode does tell the form that those fields need to be saved, but ONLY if something changes on the form manually so that the IsDirty flag is set. Any ideas on working around this issue?

Comment: Perhaps add some javascript to the OnLoad event that just sets one of those fields to null and then back to the correct value? That should trigger the IsDirty logic. You might even be able to get away with setting the field to itself, but CRM might be smarter than that. :)